# How to make SCHTASKS /Query display the "multiple actions" attribute in query result?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, batch, script

I want to display all details about a certain task.

For example, I have a "MyTask" that has multiple programs to run as **actions**, shown below:
[image]

I want to see the list of programs that the task runs in the command line version of task scheduler (or: **schtasks**).

So when I run:

```
SCHTASKS /Query /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\MyTask" /FO list /v
```

But I only get the phrase "multiple actions" instead of the actual actions / program to be run as shown below:
[image]

I know I could use the `/XML` argument to show the list of the programs to be run, but what if I have many tasks to generate results for? I want my output to be a list i.e. `/FO list`

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Batch Script List All Task Scheduler Job Names and Commands

I've provided batch script below that will run from **Windows 7** and **Windows 10**.

> **Essentially this will:**
>
> 1. Run [schtasks](https://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html) with the `/XML` switch and pipe all the *XML* content it reads through the
>      [findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) command with the `I`
>      switch (case insensitive) filtering it to only redirect the lines that
>      contain the `<!--` and `<command>` strings as ouput to a flat file.
> 2. The flat file content is then run through a dynamic **PowerShell** script that will replace the *XML* tags with more appropriately
>      formatted field names, trim any leading white space from all lines,
>      remove all blank line, and lastly  put a new line before each of the
>      `Task Name` fields but it'll skip the first line as it won't need to
>      have a line before it—the topmost line in the file.
>
> **Note:** See the ***Gotchas*** section below for potential anomaly detail and items to note.

---

### The Batch Script

```
@ECHO ON

SET RptFile=%temp%\TaskSchedReport.txt

:: -- This routine sets temp files
SET RptFileTmp=%temp%\~tmpTaskSchedReport.txt
IF EXIST "%RptFileTmp%" DEL /Q /F "%RptFileTmp%"
SET TmpPSScript=%Temp%\~tmpScheduleTasks.ps1
IF EXIST "%TmpPSScript%" DEL /Q /F "%TmpPSScript%"

:SchTask
schtasks /query /XML | Findstr /I "<!-- <command>">"%RptFileTmp%"

:PowerShell
ECHO $origFile = "%RptFileTmp%"                                                    >> "%TmpPSScript%"
ECHO $NewFile = "%RptFile%"                                                        >> "%TmpPSScript%"
ECHO $BlankLine = "`r`n"                                                           >> "%TmpPSScript%"
ECHO (Get-Content $origFile) ^| Foreach-Object {                                   >> "%TmpPSScript%"
ECHO     $_ -replace "<!-- ", 'Task Name (and path): ' -replace "<Command>", 'Command: ' -replace "<[^>]+>", '' -replace '^^\s+', '' -replace '(?m)^^\s*\r?\n', ''>> "%TmpPSScript%"
ECHO     } ^| Set-Content $NewFile                                                 >> "%TmpPSScript%"
ECHO (Get-Content $NewFile) ^| ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } ^| Set-Content $NewFile       >> "%TmpPSScript%"
ECHO (Get-Content $NewFile) ^| Foreach-Object {                                    >> "%TmpPSScript%"
ECHO     $_ -replace "Task Name ", ($BlankLine + "Task Name ") -replace "-->", ''  >> "%TmpPSScript%"
ECHO     } ^| Set-Content $NewFile                                                 >> "%TmpPSScript%"
ECHO (Get-Content $NewFile ^| Select-Object -Skip 1) ^| Set-Content $NewFile       >> "%TmpPSScript%"

SET PowerShellDir=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
CD /D "%PowerShellDir%"
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%TmpPSScript%'"

:: -- Below will open file to view content with the default text editor
explorer.exe "%RptFile%"
```

---

### Results

```
Task Name (and path): \Adobe Acrobat Update Task 
Command: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\ARM\1.0\AdobeARM.exe

Task Name (and path): \GoogleUpdateTaskMachineCore 
Command: C:\Program Files\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe

Task Name (and path): \GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA 
Command: C:\Program Files\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe

Task Name (and path): \TopSecret 
Command: C:\Folder\CIA.exe
Command: C:\Folder\FBI.exe
```

---

### Gotchas

If you notice a `Task Name` field item with no `Command` field item beneath it, that appears to be due to system scheduled tasks, etc. that have `Actions` listed as `Custom Handler` values than cannot be edited see examples and screen shot below.

**Example** (no commands)

```
Task Name (and path): \Microsoft\Windows\Shell\WindowsParentalControls 

Task Name (and path): \Microsoft\Windows\Shell\WindowsParentalControlsMigration 

Task Name (and path): \Microsoft\Windows\SideShow\AutoWake 

Task Name (and path): \Microsoft\Windows\SideShow\GadgetManager 

Task Name (and path): \Microsoft\Windows\SideShow\SessionAgent 

Task Name (and path): \Microsoft\Windows\SideShow\SystemDataProviders
```

**Task Scheduler Job Settings** (ones with no commands/actions)
[image]

---

### Further Resources

- [SCHTASKS](https://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html)
- [Findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [Regular Expressions](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-regex.html)
- [Get-Content](https://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)
- [Replace](https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html)
- [Set-Content](https://ss64.com/ps/set-content.html)
- [Trim()](https://ss64.com/ps/trim.html)
- [Comparison Operators](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-compare.html)
- [Select](https://ss64.com/ps/select-object.html)

Comment: the beauty of this is beyond words :) thank you!

Comment: This is not working for me when the paths of the actions have spaces. Example output: `Task Name (and path): \PA wake up 
Command: "C:\Users\IT Command\Documents\Batch Codes\PA\PA.bat"` and `Task Name (and path): \Example One
Command: C:\Users\IT`

Comment: It read the text after the space as an attribute

Comment: It’s when the action does not have quotes

Comment: That worked thank you. I did ask this question as well, which relates to my problem: https://superuser.com/questions/1363277/schtasks-exe-with-quotes

Comment: Well it was about the error of SchTasks not your answer which does what it is supposed to well.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say: "*I want to still see the task names in relation to what their actions are*" in the comment then you can use the below example batch script to get you the expected output with **Windows 7**.

> **Essentially this will:**
>
> 1. Run the verbose [schtasks](https://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html) query
>      command to dump the output to a csv file
> 2. With the Windows native PowerShell
>      [convertfrom-csv](https://ss64.com/ps/convertfrom-csv.html) command,
>      it'll convert the csv output to a list like format.
> 3. From there it'll use the PowerShell
>      [select](https://ss64.com/ps/select-object.html) command with the
>      `-property` switch to get only the values from the fields you want
>      to see only.
> 4. The PowerShell [where](https://ss64.com/ps/where-object.html)
>      command with `-notcontains` [comparison
>      operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-compare.html) will filter
>      out extra `TaskName` objects that for whatever reason dumps to the
>      csv file with the [schtasks](https://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html)
>      commands.
>
> Note: You're more limited with what you can and cannot use natively for this task with **Windows 7** than you are with newer Windows OSes such as **Windows 10**.

### Batch Script Explicit

You may need to play with the `-Width 256` parameter and use larger or smaller int.

```
@ECHO ON

SET RptFile=C:\Folder\Path\TaskSchedReport.txt
SET TmpPSScript=%Temp%\~tmpScheduleTasks.ps1
IF EXIST "%TmpPSScript%" DEL /Q /F "%TmpPSScript%"

ECHO schtasks /query /v /fo csv ^| ConvertFrom-CSV ^| >> "%TmpPSScript%"
ECHO Select -Property "TaskName","Task To Run" ^|     >> "%TmpPSScript%"
ECHO Where {$_.TaskName -notcontains "TaskName"} ^|   >> "%TmpPSScript%"
ECHO Out-File "%RptFile%" -Width 256                  >> "%TmpPSScript%"

SET PowerShellDir=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
CD /D "%PowerShellDir%"
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%TmpPSScript%'"

:: -- Below will open file to view content with the default text editor
explorer.exe "%RptFile%"

EXIT
```

**Batch Output Snippet**

```
TaskName                                                                                                                         Task To Run                                                                                                                    
--------                                                                                                                         -----------                                                                                                                    
\Adobe Acrobat Update Task                                                                                                       C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\ARM\1.0\AdobeARM.exe                                                                       
\Adobe Acrobat Update Task                                                                                                       C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\ARM\1.0\AdobeARM.exe                                                                       
\GoogleUpdateTaskMachineCore                                                                                                     C:\Program Files\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe /c                                                                             
\GoogleUpdateTaskMachineCore                                                                                                     C:\Program Files\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe /c                                                                             
\GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA                                                                                                       C:\Program Files\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe /ua /installsource scheduler                                                   
\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Microsoft Antimalware Scheduled Scan                                                            c:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client\\MpCmdRun.exe Scan -ScheduleJob -RestrictPrivileges                                 
\Microsoft\Windows\Active Directory Rights Management Services Client\AD RMS Rights Policy Template Management (Automated)       COM handler                                                                                                                    
\Microsoft\Windows\Active Directory Rights Management Services Client\AD RMS Rights Policy Template Management (Automated)       COM handler                                                                                                                    
\Microsoft\Windows\Active Directory Rights Management Services Client\AD RMS Rights Policy Template Management (Manual)          COM handler                                                                                                                    
\Microsoft\Windows\Autochk\Proxy                                                                                                 %windir%\system32\rundll32.exe /d acproxy.dll,PerformAutochkOperations
```

### Batch Script Everything

```
@ECHO ON

SET RptFile=C:\Folder\Path\TaskSchedReport.txt
SET TmpPSScript=%Temp%\~tmpScheduleTasks.ps1
IF EXIST "%TmpPSScript%" DEL /Q /F "%TmpPSScript%"

ECHO schtasks /query /v /fo csv ^| ConvertFrom-CSV ^| >> "%TmpPSScript%"
ECHO Where {$_.TaskName -notcontains "TaskName"} ^|   >> "%TmpPSScript%"
ECHO Out-File "%RptFile%" -Width 256                  >> "%TmpPSScript%"

SET PowerShellDir=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
CD /D "%PowerShellDir%"
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%TmpPSScript%'"

:: -- Below will open file to view content with the default text editor
explorer.exe "%RptFile%"

EXIT
```

---

### Native PowerShell Explicit

As a bonus I included the straight PowerShell syntax you can use to see the results. Test with and without without the `| FL` and compare results.

```
schtasks /query /v /fo csv | ConvertFrom-CSV |
Select -Property "TaskName","Task To Run" |
Where {$_.TaskName -notcontains "TaskName"} | FL
```

### Native PowerShell Everything

```
schtasks /query /v /fo csv | ConvertFrom-CSV |
Where {$_.TaskName -notcontains "TaskName"} | FL
```

---

### Further Resources

- [ConvertFrom-Csv](https://ss64.com/ps/convertfrom-csv.html)
- [Select](https://ss64.com/ps/select-object.html)
- [Where](https://ss64.com/ps/where-object.html)
- [Comparison Operators](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-compare.html)
- [SCHTASKS](https://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html)

Comment: what a beast answer! I am speechless. Thank you!

I'm still getting multiple actions when I run the powershell, I am assuming that's because we are using CSV as output format. Can you change that into XML and see if it works?

Comment: When I run: `schtasks /query /v /fo csv | ConvertFrom-CSV |
Select -Property "TaskName","Task To Run" |
Where {$_.TaskName -notcontains "TaskName"} | FL`
I'm still getting:
`TaskName    : \Microsoft\Windows\MyTask
Task To Run : Multiple actions`
which I suppose is normal because the CSV list doesn't contain as much info as XML. 

What I was thinking that can be the solution is to implement a 1-liner XML parser that link each "task to run" (even if multiple items) to a "task name"

got it?

Comment: please do - and thanks again for such helpful detailed answer!

Comment: sounds good; as soon as you have a working POC; please add it to the answer by editing it. thank you ALOT!