# Schtasks.exe with quotes

Tags: batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I use this command to create a task:
`schtasks /Create /TN ITCMD-CHAT-NOTIF /SC ONLOGON /tr "%cd%\Notif\Notif.vbs" /F`

However a problem occurs. When there is a space in the path it still does not put quotes around the action. Is there a way to put quotes around the action?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be accomplished by nesting the two different quote characters. (`"'` followed by `'"` or `"\"` followed by `\""`)

```dos
schtasks /Create /TN ITCMD-CHAT-NOTIF /SC ONLOGON /tr "'%cd%\Notif\Notif.vbs'" /F
```

From the `schtasks` documentation:

> ```
> ==> Spaces in file paths can be used by using two sets of quotes, one
>     set for CMD.EXE and one for SchTasks.exe.  The outer quotes for CMD
>     need to be double quotes; the inner quotes can be single quotes or
>     escaped double quotes:
>     SCHTASKS /Create
>        /tr "'c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplorer.exe'
>        \"c:\log data\today.xml\"" ...
> ```

Comment: Good job, I was getting ready to look at this in more detail too!!